# CV to tune hyperparameter in prophet

Tags: cross-validation, facebook-prophet, parameter-tuning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOXEH.png)
trying to tune parameters in prophet. If just tune the first 2 changepoint and seasonality scale, it works.
However, once I added other param such as holiday_prior_scale and seasonality_mode, always got the errors. any idea? thanks

trying to tune parameters in prophet. If just tune the first 2 changepoint and seasonality scale, it works.
However, once I added other param such as holiday_prior_scale and seasonality_mode, always got the errors. any idea? thanks